# Embed JavaScript in a Kindle ebook

Tags: javascript, kindle

Is it possible to publish an ebook for e-Ink Kindles (not Kindle Fire) that can run JavaScript inside the ebook?

Comment: For the .mobi format it's impossible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The features supported by E-Ink Kindles and Kindle Format 8 ebooks are documented in the Amazon Kindle Publishing Guidelines which can be found here: http://kindlegen.s3.amazonaws.com/AmazonKindlePublishingGuidelines.pdf

The relevant part of the document is "Kindle Format 8 supports most HTML 5.0 features, although the following HTML features are not fully supported: forms, frames, and JavaScript."

In short, you can't use JavaScript in Kindle Format 8 ebooks.

Comment: More specifically, section 6.3: Avoid Using Scripting:
"Scripting is not supported. All scripts are stripped from the source during conversion."